# how to make full css container

Tags: css, containers

I wish the container can expand and no have any space on top, left and right

This is my code.

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background:red;
}


body{
background:black;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's doing this because of the padding and margin on the html and body tags.

Add

```
html,body{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px; 
}
```

this to the top of your css. This will remove all the extra padding and margin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {margin:0px;background:#000;}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    background:red;padding:0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KUuPr/